# Dependency Injection in Net Core with configurable service implementations

Tags: .net, .net-core, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

I have multiple implementations of the same service:

```
public interface IService { }
public class ServiceA : IService { }
public class ServiceB : IService { }
```

I want to be able to define the implementation of IService in my appsettings.json, so that services can be replaced on deployment. Something like this:

```
{
   "Service": 
   {
       "class":"NameSpaceA",
       "settting":"value",
       "setting2":"value"
   }
{
```

Note that the constructors of ServiceA and ServiceB might be different and I want the DI framework to take care of resolving the dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

A pretty neat solution is writing an extension method which uses Options pattern with named options. This allows you to have zero, one or multiple implementations of a service, where each implementation has its own config.

Something like this:

```
public static class DependencyInjectionExtensions
{
        public static IServiceCollection AddConfiguredServices<TService, TConfig>(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection, string configSectionName, IConfiguration config) where TConfig : class
        {
            var configSections = config.GetSection(configSectionName).GetChildren();
            foreach (var configSection in configSections)
            {
                string name = configSection["className"] ?? throw new ConfigurationErrorsException($"className is not specified for {typeof(TService).Name} at path \"{configSection.Path}\"");
                serviceCollection.Configure<TConfig>(name, configSection);
                Type serviceType = GetType(name);
                serviceCollection.AddSingleton(typeof(TService), serviceType);
            }

            return serviceCollection;
        }
}
```

NOTE: GetType can be a simple Type.GetType call or something more complex that searches through the loaded assemblies.

This allows you to have config like this:

```
"Services": [
    {
      "className": "NamespaceA.ServiceA",
      "setting1": "...",
      "setting2": "..."
      }
    },
    {
      "className": "NamespaceB.ServiceB",
      "setting1": "...",
      "setting3": "..."
      }
    }
]
```

With that we just need an Options class:

```
public class ServiceSetttings
{
    public const string Section = "Services";
    public string Setting1 { get; set; }
    public string Setting2 { get; set; }
    public string Setting3 { get; set; }
}
```

Registration becomes a single liner:

```
serviceCollection.AddConfiguredServices<IService, ServiceSetttings>(ServiceSetttings.Section, config);
```

For completeness, here's how the service constructor looks like:

```
public class ServiceA: IService
{
    private readonly ILogger<ServiceA> logger;
    private readonly SomeOtherDependency dependency;
    private readonly string someConfig;

    public ServiceA(SomeOtherDependency dependency, IOptionsMonitor<ServiceSetttings> settings, ILogger<ServiceA> logger)
    {
        ServiceSetttings config = settings.Get(this.GetType().FullName) ?? throw new ConfigurationErrorsException($"Configuration not found for {this.GetType().FullName}");
            
        someConfig = config.Setting1;
        this.dependency= dependency;
        this.logger = logger;
    }
    //Service Code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `ConfigureServices` method of your `Startup` class, you should read the fully qualified type name from the configuration, convert it into a type, and add it to the `IServiceCollection`. For instance:

```cs
IConfigurationSection settings = this.Configuration.GetSection("Service");
string typeName = settings.GetValue<string>("class");
Type type = Type.GetType(typeName, throwOnError: true);
services.AddTransient(typeof(IService), type);
```

This instructs the DI Container to use the late-bound type as implementation for the `IService` abstraction. The DI Container will use Auto-Wiring to construct the type, which means it will analyze its constructor at runtime. `ServiceA` and `ServiceB` can have different constructor signatures, but the container can resolve them nonetheless.

Comment: That's pretty much what I went with. However, I needed multiple implementations with their respective configurations, so the solution was a bit more complex. See my own answer for the details.